# .NET Core Singleton Creation is called multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm registering a service as a singleton in .NET Core.  Yet I'm seeing the constructor for the singleton called multiple times.

```
services.AddSingleton<DbAuthorizationOptions, ContextAuthorizationOptions>();
```

My context authorization options is just Dictionary of Entity Types to `IValidators`,  The context authorization options are passed into the `DBContext`, to automatically run validations.

During the registration of my services,  I also register dynamic Validators with my container registered in DI.

```
var useDynamicValidator = serviceOption.ValidatorOptions != null;
if(useDynamicValidator)
{
    //TODO: Extract this to before the register service no sense in building the provider each time
    //TODO: Make this cleaner don't be dependent on Authorization options
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var authOptions = provider.GetService<DbAuthorizationOptions>();
    var validator = BuildDynamicValidatorFactory(serviceOption).Invoke(provider, null);
    authOptions.ValidatorOptions.AddValidatorForSet(validator);
}
```

I notice that when I call `GetService` on the provider I receive a new singleton instead of the existing one.  Does building the provider create a new container so all of the services get re-registered?

If so,  How can I call a method to register my dynamic validators in the singleton container with the existing `IServiceProvider`, is there a way to invoke some registration once after the service container is built?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does building the provider create a new container so all of the services get reregistered?

Yes. See [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/a0467de767febbf86b7d401abe012da8434fa7d7/src/DI/ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.cs#L59).

> If so, How can I call a method to register my dynamic validators in the singleton container with the existing IServiceProvider, is there a way to invoke some registration once after the servicecontainer is built?

I'm not really understanding why this is a problem. You should be registering all of your services *one time* at application startup in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

The DI container is then responsible for resolving the *object graphs* of the application. The application itself shouldn't have a dependency on it, nor be required to update it.

You should be *injecting* `DbAuthorizationOptions` in the place where you need to use it.

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly DbAuthorizationOptions authOptions;

    public Foo(DbAuthorizationOptions authOptions) // <-- Inject parameters
    {
        this.authOptions = authOptions ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authOptions));
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // TODO: Inject the type that has the BuildDynamicValidatorFactory
        // method and the serviceOption (whatever type that is) here
        // either as a method parameter of this method, or a constructor
        // parameter of this class.
        var validator = BuildDynamicValidatorFactory(serviceOption).Invoke(provider, null);
        // Now we have an instance of authOptions that can be used
        authOptions.ValidatorOptions.AddValidatorForSet(validator);
    }
}
```

Note that the DI container *automatically* provides the `DbAuthorizationOptions` if injected into another type that is also resolved through DI (such as a controller or filter).

> **NOTE:** It isn't very clear from your question where you need to do this. You mention that you want it to happen once, which *usually* means to put it at application startup. But users cannot interact with code that runs at startup. So, maybe you could use a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters). It really all depends on *where* in the lifecycle of the application it has to happen.

Comment: I have a component which is dependent on having access to all of the Validators for any Entity in a context.  I register a singleton a dictionary of EntityTypes to Validator.  When the use registers with service factory, If there is not a concrete validator declare, the user can provide options passed to my service to create a dynamic validator.  This dynamic validator needs to be registered with the singleton so the context has access to all the validators.  So I need to register my dynamic validators once after the service container is built, How can I do this?

Comment: See my edit. If you inject `authOptions` and it is a singleton, you should be able to access it in any service. So, at runtime you can build the factory and add the validation. I am not exactly sure where `serviceOption` comes from, so you will either need to inject it through the constructor or pass it as a method parameter. If it doesn't make sense, you should probably edit the question to provide some more context as to what your setup is like (or better yet, since this seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), ask a new question).

Comment: @johnny5 ... NightOwl888's factory pattern is the right approach, but to directly answer your question, the .NET Core DI container doesn't support adding services later on. My earlier answer about injecting `IServiceProvider` would fix your not-a-singleton problem, but it's the "service locator" anti-pattern which you generally want to avoid.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I'm not sure if this will work with my implementation but it hard to explain my full problem with out dumping pages of code here.  I'll investigate both solutions to see which will work better

Comment: @NightOwl888 thanks I ended up using a modified version of this

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what the point of a singleton is if it is created anew every place it is used and not shared across usages.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a dependency on `IServiceProvider` -- don't build it, inject it.

```
public class SomeController
{
    DbAuthorizationOptions authOptions;
    public SomeController(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        authOptions = provider.GetSerivce<DbAuthorizationOptions>();
    }
}
```

But this is the [service locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) anti-pattern. As I commented on NightOwl888's post after you gave more details, a factory is probably a better approach.

Comment: what do you mean don't build it just inject it? how can I inject it?

Comment: Interesting I'll need to investigate whether in my case it's possible to use the factory approach, this should work though

Comment: Actually, there is no factory in the solution I gave (beyond the one I copied and pasted). My solution *injects* the `DbAuthorizationOptions`. This solution *resolves* the `DbAuthorizationOptions` using a service locator. It looks the same on paper, but the difference is that when you inject `IServiceProvider` you are *tightly coupling* the code to `IServiceProvider` so it cannot live without this extra interface. If you want to swap out `DbAuthorizationOptions` for another implementation or a mock, you have more hoops to jump through using the service locator approach.