# Can't use registered singetons in ConfigureServices without them being instantiated twice

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, asp.net-core-2.0, service-locator

I have a .Net Core project that registers a number of Singletons as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddLogging();

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IDbFactory, DefaultDbFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();    
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();          
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BackgroundService>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISettingsRepository, SettingsRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(TokenManager));

    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var userRepository = sp.GetService<IUserRepository>();
    // ...
}
```

This is the only place these classes are registered, and no other instances are created anywhere, however I have noticed that the constructors are called twice.  Why is that?

Comment: Why do you need a user repository before the services are configured? You should be able to inject an `IServiceProvider` into a later method and do it there.

Comment: @nvoigt good question which probably deserves another SO question.  The reason is that I'm adding framework services below this which include a custom Role based authorization filter, which is constructed with the user repository. This doesn't feel right to me as it creates a hard dependency, however it's not the point of this question and answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR - If you need one of your registered singletons to be passed in as a configuration option to `AddMvc`, **Don't** do what I did and use `GetService` in the `ConfigureServices` method. Skip down to EDIT 2 below.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48856563/2869344) to a similar question but the answer wasn't clear about the order with respect to the service registration, however it did point out that calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()` builds a new container which causes the services to be reregistered.  Kind of makes sense in hindsight...

**EDIT:**

My original fix was to move `services.BuildServiceProvider()` before the `AddSingleton` registrations, however it turns out this doesn't always work, as Buddha Buddy pointed out.

I've just seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459670/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di) which gives a lot more detail into what's happening.  The original registrations are not discarded, as I thought they were. I was thinking about it all wrong.

Calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()` does build a new service provider/container, but this has nothing to do with registrations.  The class implementing `IUserRepository` and all dependent services are instantiated *by the new service provider* when `sp.GetService<IUserRepository>()` is called, but the original `IServiceProvider` remains, and that's what the rest of the application will use.

So down the line when the application requires an instance of `IUserRepository` (say because it's an injected dependency of `UsersController`, which has now been requested), the `IUserRepository` service (and its dependencies, if any) are again instantiated, because it's now under the original `IServiceProvider`.

A comment in the answer to the question above states that you can prevent this and use the one `IServiceProvider`, *"by returning the service provider instance from the `ConfigureServices` method so that will be the container your application uses as well"*. I'm not sure how you would do that short of storing a class variable pointing to it, so it can be swapped out in the `Configure` method by setting `app.ApplicationServices` - but that doesn't work for me either, because the new service provider is missing all the MVC services.

Some people recommend using the `app.ApplicationServices` in `Configure()` to access the required service instead, but that won't work for me as I need to use it in `ConfigureServices` as follows:

```
//...

serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var userRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<IUserRepository>();

// Add framework services
services.AddMvc(

    config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new RolesAuthorizationFilter(userRepository));
    });
```

**EDIT 2:**

Found the solution!  [This brilliant post](https://andrewlock.net/accessing-services-when-configuring-mvcoptions-in-asp-net-core/) described what I was trying to achieve and presented a very tidy solution.

If you need to pass a reference to one of your registered singletons in as MVC configuration options, rather than try and instantiate it inside `ConfigureServices`, you can simply create a new class that implements `IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>` which can take injected dependencies, register this class as a singleton - *and everything else is taken care of - brilliant!*

Example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddLogging();

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IDbFactory, DefaultDbFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();    
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();          
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BackgroundService>();
    services.AddSingleton<ISettingsRepository, SettingsRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(TokenManager));

    // var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider(); // NO NEED for this after all
    // var userRepository = sp.GetService<IUserRepository>();

    services.AddMvc(); // No config options required any more
    services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, ConfigureMvcOptions>();  // Here be the magic...

    // ...
}
```

Then create the new class:

```
public class ConfigureMvcOptions : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;
    public ConfigureMvcOptions(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new RolesAuthorizationFilter(userRepository));
    }
}
```

Thanks to the magic of DI, everything else is taken care of. My user repository singleton and its dependencies are only instantiated once.

Comment: Moving the BuildServiceProvider to before registering didn't work for me. I got a "No service for type 'IMySingleton' has been registered.' exception. Instead, I moved the singleton initialization to Startup.Configure() by using app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IMySingleton>(), and now I don't have multiple instances of my singleton created. In my case, I have a long running action that needs to start immediately, not waiting for someone to call my service, and I want the service to be unavailable until this process is finished.

Answer (score 0):

While instantiating a singleton within `ConfigureServices` is arguably code smell, it *is* possible. Simply re-register the singleton *instance* you've instantiated within the `ConfigureServices` scope:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();    
    // ...

    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var userRepository = sp.GetService<IUserRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository>(userRepository);    
    // ...
}
```

This ensures downstream attempts to inject a `IUserRepository` will use the instance you created within `ConfigureServices` instead of creating a new instance.